# Firebase Crashlytics permissions issue

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am unable access Crashlytics, it is showing the below message.

```
To manage Crashlytics, ask a project owner for the necessary permissions.
```

[image]

By default, every user will have viewing permission, but it is showing this error message asking the permissions.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Add this permission:
[image: Where the advanced settings needs to be added]

And these guys:

[image: Error permissions]

Take note to not add the "Deprecated" version of the permission.

You can see that permission on the Advanced Permission Settings. (Project Overview -> Project Settings -> Users and Permissions -> Advanced Permission Settings)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It looks like an owner hasn't yet gone through the flow to enable Crashlytics. Until an owner of the project takes these steps you'll be unable to access the dashboard. If you think this has happened, please contact support and we'll look into it with you :)