# Firebase Crashlytics role in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, crashlytics

Because of GDPR we are trying to limit access for the developers to production data, but the developers need access to Crashlytics. I have tried to add the roles specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50585767/328864:

- Firebase Crash Symbol Uploader
- Error Reporting User
- Error Reporting Viewer
- Error Writer

..but it doesn't work, the page only says `The project XXXX either does not exist, or XXXX doesn't have permission to view it.`. I have also tried to add a bunch of other roles, like *Error Reporting Admin*, *Monitoring Admin* etc, but it doesn't make any difference. The only role that seems to work is *Project - Viewer*, but that also gives read access to the entire database.

Is there a role or combination of roles that gives access to only Firebase Crashlytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding one of the Firebase Quality predefined roles?
[image: Firebase Quality roles]

I followed the post you referenced to grant access for my Viewer members and it didn't work. Only after adding Firebase Quality Admin role did the users get access. I didn't try the Firebase Quality Viewer role because I wanted those members to be able to link app from Fabric.

I realize this may not be what you want as this will provide access to the other Quality services, but just want to throw it out there as an option.

Comment: Wow, that seems to work perfectly, thanks! These roles must have been added recently, because I don't recognize them? :)

Comment: I don't know when these were added TBH but glad they're available now and helped!

Comment: How did you open the dlg?

Comment: @NickUnuchek since answering this post, the Firebase team has updated their UI. Now, in order to assign Firebase roles, when you're in "Users and permissions," click on the row for the user you're trying to update and a "Roles" popup will appear. Click on "Assign Firebase role(s)" and check either Admin or Viewer for Quality under Quality.